# Copy text from Word to Excel based on a list of search words

Tags: excel, vba, search, text, ms-word

Hello dear forum members,

in the context of a research work at my university I have to transfer text passages from Word documents into an Excel file based on keywords.

This is a list of keywords (all listed below each other in an Excel column) and several Word documents (about 80-100 with 400 pages each).

The program should search the Word document for the keywords and if a word is found, the corresponding word + 350 characters before and after the word should be copied to an Excel line. Additionally, the name of the document and the number of pages should be copied. Each found word should be copied into a new line.

Based on first researches at Google I have received the following code. Most of it already works with this code.

I need your help with the following two points:

1.)  How can I extend the text to be copied? If a search word is found in the word document, the word + 350 characters before and after the word should be copied.

2.) How should a loop look like, so that all Word documents in a folder are processed one after the other?

Since I did not find a solution after trying for a long time, I am happy about every tip or solution.

```
Sub LocateSearchItem_Test22()
Dim shtSearchItem As Worksheet
Dim shtExtract As Worksheet
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim WordNotOpen As Boolean
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oRange As Word.Range
Dim LastRow As Long                 
Dim CurrRowShtSearchItem As Long    
Dim CurrRowShtExtract As Long      
Dim myPara As Long
Dim myLine As Long
Dim myPage As Long
Dim oDocName As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err Then
        Set oWord = New Word.Application
        WordNotOpen = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\Data fronm Word to Excel\Testdatei.docx")       

    oDocName = ActiveDocument.Name

    Set shtSearchItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=shtSearchItem
    End If
    Set shtExtract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    LastRow = shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows(shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 2 To LastRow
        Set oRange = oDoc.Range
        With oRange.Find
            .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
            .MatchCase = False
            '.MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            While oRange.Find.Execute = True
                oRange.Select
                myPara = oDoc.Range(0, oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count
                myPage = oWord.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
                myLine = oWord.Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)

                CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1).Value = .Text
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 2).Value = myPara
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 3).Value = myPage
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 4).Value = myLine
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 5).Value = oDocName
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 6) = oDoc.Paragraphs(myPara).Range

                oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

            Wend
        End With
    Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

    If WordNotOpen Then
        oWord.Quit
    End If

    'Release object references

    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    If WordNotOpen Then
        oWord.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to specifically focus on the Word part, because that is my expertise. It looks like you know a fair bit about VBA, so I'm just going to answer with snippets.

Here's your find:

```vb
With oRange.Find
    .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
    .MatchCase = False
    '.MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True 'do you really want wildcards?
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    While .Execute = True
        myPara = oDoc.Range(0, oRange.End).Paragraphs.Count
        myPage = oRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        myLine = oRange.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
'Expand range size begins here        
        oRange.MoveStart wdCharacter, -350 'not sure if you want the info of just the word or the word +/- 350 characters
        oRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 350

        CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1).Value = .Text
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 2).Value = myPara
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 3).Value = myPage
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 4).Value = myLine
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 5).Value = oDocName
                    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 6) = oRange.Text

                oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
End With
```

Don't select anything, ever, if you can help it. Almost everything in Word can be done without ever ever ever using selection. Declare the range and manipulate the range. There's no need to select it.

As far as looping through each document in the folder, take a look at `FileSystemObject`. The documentation is horrendous but Google results are generally pretty good.

Comment: Hi, Jclasley,

thank you very much for the solution and the further tips. 
I know the problem concerning "Selection", but at the moment my VBA knowledge is not sufficient to work with Range. 

Have a nice day and best regards
Aaron

Comment: It's harder to avoid with Word than with Excel, so don't worry too much about it. Word VBA is how I learned so it's ingrained in me to avoid it all costs. In the long run, it's worth it to learn how to manipulate ranges. If the code works, come back and update the answer as accepted for anyone who might have the same question in the future.